# array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array

Tags: php, arrays

Need someone to help me to crack the following.

On my local machine, i'm running MAMP on my Mac. I have the following code:

```
   $x=0;
   for ($i=0; $i<=30; $i++) {
       $VoteValue[$x] = $i;
       $x++;
   }

   $Total = array_sum($VoteValue);
   echo "<br /><br />Total Vote = $Total <br />";
```

The above code works and run fine on my local machine. But, when I uploaded it to my production server, I get the following warning prompts:

```
Warning: array_sum() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given in /home/RIP/public_html/RIPVote.php on line 7
```

and it doesn't return and show the output value due to the warning error. How do i get rid of this?

Please advice and looking forward to hear from you guys soon. Appreciate and thanks.

Comment: Do a `var_dump` immediately before you call `array_sum`...

Comment: Not sure if this is necessary, but have you tried adding `$VoteValue = array()` before the loop?

Comment: Thanks Oli and Kieran, got it sorted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, weird, i dont know what the error is in your code, but try this out :

```
$VoteValue = array();
for ($i=0; $i<=30; $i++) {
           $VoteValue[] = $i;
       }

       $Total = array_sum($VoteValue);
       echo "<br /><br />Total Vote = $Total <br />";
```

Answer (score 6):

Have you tried initializing $VoteValue with

```
$VoteValue = array();
```

?

As a total aside, the sum from 0 to n = ( n * (n+1) ) / 2.

Comment: Would work indeed if `$VoteValue` is a string before, short explanation: `$VoteValue[n]=$something` would then replace the n-th character with the first character of `$something`, and just remain an (altered) string.

Answer (score 2):

try this way. I hope to be helpful

```
$VoteValue = [];

for ($i=0; $i<=30; $i++) {
     array_push($VoteValue, $i);
}

$Total = array_sum($VoteValue);

echo "<br /><br />Total Vote = $Total <br />";
```

Answer (score 1):

i'v tried,on the ubuntu11.04 with lampp.
no errors.

> Total Vote = 465

maybe the php problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
       $VoteValue = range(0, 30);
       $Total = array_sum($VoteValue);
       echo "<br /><br />Total Vote = $Total <br />";
?>
```

You can use `range()` or `array_fill()`

Compact code:

```
<?php echo '<br /><br />Total Vote = '.array_sum(range(0, 30)).' <br />'; ?>
```